# ORFEO vs ERDAS: How to extract a good DSM with ORFEO

Tags: erdas-imagine, orfeo-toolbox, results, dem

I'm trying to use ORFEO to check is it suitable to replace ERDAS to perform DSM extraction from stereo pairs. First thing, I can't use ORFEO for complete Pleiades images, it always crashes (my machine has 8gb of ram and I use Kubuntu 14.04). Second, I started to use a part of my pair to make the process (1024x1024 pixels). This way ORFEO works, but, the resulting DSM is not as good as a DSM generated by ERDAS. Is anyone able to get good results with ORFEO regarding DSM extraction? I've used the same images and area used in this course (https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/packages/OTBCourses.pdf)

ORFEO DSM:

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that you've applied the same commands as in the OTB tutorials (section 3.7) with the same parameters? This example was done with OTB 4.2. If you're not able to reproduce the same results on the same area with the same parameters there is probably something to investigate. Please report in this case to otb mantis if you can: https://bugs.orfeo-toolbox.org/my_view_page.php Manuel

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've used the same parameters but I downloaded the image this weekend. I've learned that Airbus updated some Pleiades samples... But still, playing with median filter parameter I was able to improve my DSM but the trees and the grass inside the stadium are still very spiky. Other thing, I can't use the StereoFramework, it always crashes (Monteverdi2 v0.8.1). Are you able to use the StereoFramework? Can you show me the parameters you use for the test area in Melbourne? Thank you very much!